# Laravel Pagination using JQUERY and AJAX

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, pagination, laravel-8

When I clicked the next page, only the JSON data is showing, why is that? I'm stuck in here for about two days. Please help :(
**here is the script in blade view**

```
        $(document).ready(function() {

        fetchassociate();

        function fetchassociate() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/fetch-associate",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(response) {
                    $('tbody').html("");
                    $.each(response.associate.data, function(key, associates) {
                        $('tbody').append('<tr>\
                                  <td>' + associates.associate_id + '</td>\
                                  <td>' + associates.last_name + ', ' + associates.first_name + ' ' + associates.middle_name + '</td>\
                                  <td>' + associates.username + '</td>\
                                  <td>' + associates.email + '</td>\
                                  <td>' + associates.phone + '</td>\
                                  <td>' + associates.gender + '</td>\
                                  <td><button type = "button" value = "' + associates.associate_id + '" class = "edit_associate btn btn-primary btn-sm">Edit</button>\
                                  <button type = "button" value = "' + associates.associate_id + '" class = "delete_associate btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</button></td>\
                                </tr>');
                    });
                    $.each(response.associate.links, function(key, link) {
                        $('#tablefoot').append( '<ul class="pagination pagination-sm m-0 float-left">\
                <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="'+link.url+'">'+link.label+'</a></li>\
                </ul>');
                    });
                }

            });
        }
    }
```

**HERE IS THE CONTROLLER**

```
    public function fetchassociate()
{
    $associate = User::join('associate', 'associate.associate_id', '=', 'users.id')
    ->orderBy('last_name', 'ASC')
    ->paginate(5); 
    return response()->json([
        'associate' => $associate,
    ]);
}
```

**ROUTE**

```
Route::get('fetch-associate', [ManageController::class, 'fetchassociate']);
```

[The output when I click the next page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLWUx.png)

Comment: Is the first page working ok? Can you post your output  here as text instead of a image.

Comment: @Grumpy The view is showing the first 5 data. However when I click the page number 1, it also shows the JSON data just like when clicking the page number 2. Here is the text of the output your looking for. [link](https://products.groupdocs.app/viewer/view?file=ade86226-1de5-41da-be71-8cdf696896e5/Output%20when%20page%202%20is%20clicked.txt) Thank you.